# Using ng-model with template prepended after linking to directive template

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a dom structure where on `save()`, i have to capture the values of the `<input>` tags. This works fine as long as i have the `<input>` defined within template of the directive.

```
template:
    '<div>' +
    '<input type="text" ng-model="value1"><br><br>' +
    '<input type="text" ng-model="value2"><br><br>' +
    '<button ng-click="clicked()">Load View</button>' +
    '<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>' +
    '</div>'
```

[Here is the plunker for the same.](http://plnkr.co/edit/uOvTqmQStANZ5yvfHOrt?p=preview)

But when i try to prepend the code to the already loaded template:

```
var view =
    '<input type="text" ng-model="value1"><br><br>' +
    '<input type="text" ng-model="value2"><br><br>'; 
element.prepend(view);
```

The binding of value1 to the directive scope doesnt work.

[Plunker for this](http://plnkr.co/edit/av6G0FIMkaq5TpiLj60e?p=preview)

Comment: You need to $compile it

Comment: Oh yes. That makes sense.